# Is it natural to use the verb "give" when asking someone for something to use for some time?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say I need a pen. Is appropriet to use *give* when asking someone for it to use for some time? For example:

> Can you **give** me your pen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it natural to use the verb "take" in the sense of borrowing something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232723/is-it-natural-to-use-the-verb-take-in-the-sense-of-borrowing-something)

Comment: I got the good answer for the question in this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sometimes*, the context will be such that your example wouldn't be taken as a rude / peremptory "demand". But often it would be, so I suggest you avoid it and ask instead...

> *Can/Could I **borrow** your pen?*
>    *Will/Would you **lend** me your pen?*
>    *Can/Might/May I use your pen?*

Obviously if you want to be absolutely sure your utterance is seen more as a polite request than as an imperative demand, you should also include "the magic word" *(**Please**)*.

---

Also note that although native speakers *sometimes* ask to be ***given*** something even when it's only needed temporarily (and will shortly be returned), as a non-native speaker you should probably avoid this. Stick with ***lend*** or similar to avoid unwanted misunderstandings.