# Is it natural to use the verb "take" in the sense of borrowing something?

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to use *take* in the sense of borrowing something. For example:

> Can I **take** your phone?

If it fine, than is it more common to use take instead of *borrow*?

Comment: The only thing unusual about the sentence in the question is the use of *you* instead of *your*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for borrowing (with permission from the owner) it is more common to use **borrow**.

**Take** refers more to taking the object permanently (without permission from the owner).

That doesn't mean that **take** can never be used when it's intended to return the borrowed object.

E.g

> Can I take your car to work?

Here it's fine to use take, since it's a temporary action (you don't take the car permanently, but only for a given amount of time).

Answer (score 5):

> Can I take *your* phone.

In the right context, this could mean "borrow", but that does not mean the words are always interchangeable.

"Take" could mean taking something permanently. It could also mean taking something along on a specific trip or journey. For example, if I asked my daughter to go to the shops and she asked "can I take your phone" it would be clear that she was taking the phone to the shops and that she would return with it; but if a bailiff "took" your phone it would be understood you weren't getting it back.

If the request was unprompted then the asker would almost certainly use "borrow" to establish what they wanted.

Comment: Uh... my understanding is that a bailiff *should* return your personal belongings when you leave jail, unless it’s evidence or something (and even then, you should get the phone back *eventually* unless somehow the forensic needs of the case require doing something to it that destroys the phone).

Comment: @KRyan in England and Wales, bailiffs are court officers who recover property or seize it to satisfy a debt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailiff#England_and_Wales

Answer (score 2):

It is uncommon to use *take* to indicate you are going to borrow something.

*Take* is the act of gaining posession of something and can include taking something permanently or taking something without permission.

While *take* can be use to describe the part of borrowing where you gain posession of the item, it would be less clear that it will be returned.